# c# How do I pass the value of the DataGrid Cell into a converter?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

How do I pass the value of the `DataGridCell` into the `Foreground` property converter?

So `GooglePositionConvertor` will return a value created from the object passed by Path=. however I want to change the cell style foreground colour based on the value returned by `GooglePositionConvertor`.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource GooglePositionConvertor}}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{????????????, Converter={StaticResource ChangeBrushColour}}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do not specify binding path - Foreground property will receive the DataContext of DataGridCell as binding source.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ColorList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrush}}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I need the object that's binded to the row for the first converter "GooglePositionConvertor" but just the value of the cell for the second converter "ChangeBrushColour".

Answer (score 0):

You could bind to the `Content` property of the `DataGridCell` and use a `DependencyPropertyDescriptor` to be able to set the `Foreground` property of the `TextBlock` once its `Text` property has been set:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource GooglePositionConvertor}}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                Converter={StaticResource ChangeBrushColour}}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

---

```
public class Converter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        TextBlock content = value as TextBlock;
        if(content != null)
        {
            string text = content.Text;
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                DependencyPropertyDescriptor dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(TextBlock.TextProperty, typeof(TextBlock));
                if (dpd != null)
                    dpd.AddValueChanged(content, OnTextChanged);
            }
            else
            {
                OnTextChanged(content, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    private void OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock textBlock = sender as TextBlock;
        string converterText = textBlock.Text;
        //set foreground based on text...
        textBlock.Foreground = Brushes.Violet;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```